# From $\langle v,u_0\rangle=\langle v,u_1\rangle$ for all $v\in V$, show that $u_0=u_1.$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

$u_0$ and $u_1$ are vectors in the inner product space V with $\langle u_0,v\rangle=\langle u_1,v\rangle$ for all $v\in V$.

Show that $u_0=u_1$ (let $v=u_0-u_1$).

I'm would be glad to have a little pointer.

**EDIT**:

I get:

$\langle u_0-u_1,v=0\rangle$. If we let $v=u_0-u_1$:

$\langle v,v\rangle=0 \Rightarrow \vec{v}=\vec{0}$ and so $\vec{u_0}=\vec{u_1}=\vec{0}$

Is this correct?

Comment: "let $v=u_0 - u_1$" is a very good start... use the bilinearity of the inner product, the given property and this $v$.

Comment: Do you mean $\langle u_0, v\rangle = \langle u_1, v\rangle$?

Comment: @Michael Albanese I assumed this was the case, otherwise the problem is not reasonable...

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\langle u_0, v \rangle = \langle u_1,v \rangle$ we have $\langle u_0 - u_1, v\rangle = 0 $ for all $v \in V$. Now we can take $v = u_{0} - u_{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\langle u_0,v\rangle&=\langle u_1,v\rangle\iff \langle u_0-u_1,v\rangle=0\;\;\forall\,v\in V\\
\langle u,u\rangle&=0\iff u=0\end{align*}$$

Comment: shouldn't it be $\langle u_0,u_1\rangle=0$?

Comment: or should it be $\langle v,v\rangle=0$? If this is the case I can't see what that says about the u-vectors.

Comment: Since the given relation (the right one in my first line) is true **for all** $\,v\in V\;$, you can then *choose* $\;v=u_0-u_1\;$ , use this in the 2nd. line and you're done...